# How do I pull HTML form option values?

Tags: perl

Autotrader's website has a form called 'searchVehicle'. In that form are a number of HTML  values for the given form input fields `qr/^(radius|make|model|price-to)`. These  values are as you'd expect, i.e. a drop-down list. How do I pull the string values of those `<option>`'s?

So far I have the following Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
binmode STDIN, ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my $url = 'https://www.autotrader.co.uk/';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize -> new( autocheck => 1 );
$mech -> agent_alias( 'Linux Mozilla');

if ($mech -> status( $mech -> get($url)) == 200)
{
    $mech -> form_name('searchVehicles');
    my @inputs = $mech -> find_all_inputs(
                            name_regex    => qr/^(radius|make|model|price-to)$/,
                            type    =>  'option',);
    print Dumper \@inputs;
};
```

My result is like:

```
$VAR1 = [
          bless( {
                   'idx' => 1,
                   'type' => 'option',
                   'current' => 0,
                   'name' => 'radius',
                   'menu' => [
                               {
                                 'name' => 'Select the distance',
                                 'seen' => 1,
                                 'value' => ''
                               }
                             ],
                   'id' => 'radius',
                   'aria-label' => 'Choose a radius',
                   'class' => 'c-form__select'
                 }, 'HTML::Form::ListInput' ),
          bless( {
                 }, 'HTML::Form::ListInput' ),
          bless( {
                 }, 'HTML::Form::ListInput' ),
          bless( {
                 }, 'HTML::Form::ListInput' )
        ];
```

Note: I have truncated all but the first since you get the idea with the first.

- How do I return the `'HTML::Form::ListInput'` values?

Comment: Can you offer the URL of the actual page?

Comment: @zdim - I've edited the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [WWW::Mechanize::find_all_inputs](http://search.cpan.org/~oalders/WWW-Mechanize-1.88/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#$mech-%3Efind_all_inputs%28_..._criteria_..._%29) says

> find_all_inputs() returns an array of all the input controls in the current form whose properties match all of the regexes passed in. The controls returned are all descended from HTML::Form::Input. See ["INPUTS" in HTML::Form](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Form-6.03/lib/HTML/Form.pm#INPUTS) for details.

So your `@inputs` is an array of [HTML::Form](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Form-6.03/lib/HTML/Form.pm) objects.

From the given link to its `INPUTS` section we find methods like `name`, `value`, `value_names`, and many others. This is what you use to pull the needed information.

**Update for the actual site that was provided**

However, pages on this site are organized in a way that requires a bit more. The given URL does not list values anywhere (use Ctrl-U to see source), relegating `action` to `/car-search`.

When we load *that* page then we can use the above discussion.  The code below aims to show how to retrieve information, please adjust for maintainability

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use WWW::Mechanize;

use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

#my $url = 'https://www.autotrader.co.uk';
my $url = 'https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );
my $status = $mech->status( $mech->get($url) );
die "Got $status\n" if $status != 200;

$mech->form_number(2);

my @inputs = $mech -> find_all_inputs(
    name_regex => qr/^(radius|make|model|price-to)$/,
    type       =>  'option'
);

foreach my $input (@inputs) {
    say "input: ", $input->name;
    say join ' ', $input->possible_values;
    say "\t$_" for $input->value_names;
}
```

Output, with categories truncated for convenience

```
input: radius
1500 1 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60 70 80 90 100 200
        Distance (national)
        Within 1 mile
        Within 5 miles
        ...
input: price-to
500 1000 1500 2000 2500 3000 3500 4000 4500 5000 5500 [...]
        (any)
        £500 (934)
        £1,000 (7,683)
        ...
```

Only `radius` and `price-to` are in this form. The other terms of interest are in different HTML elements further down the source, and have to be retrieved in other ways.

Comment: @uncle-junky Thank you, I've just looked at it and can query all components of the form using the methods like the ones in the answer.. So what do you want to do? Presumably now you'd fill and submit the form etc. What "values" do you want -- can you give an example?

Comment: How do I access the values of radius|make|model|price-to ?

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood. In my code I have returned an array of hashes. I can access all the values that are listed in the Dumper output if I loop over the `@inputs` array and print only the current loop's hash key, but I am after the values of the `<option>` tags. For example, in the website `searchVehicles` form there is a input field for Distance. The drop-down gives you choices between 1 to 200 miles. How do I obtain those values?

Comment: I've undeleted the post.

Comment: @uncle-junky Alright, here it is, restored.  Note: I don't respond well to whimsical -1 and I intend to remove it, unless the score changes. So please use it and let me know when you are done. Let me know if there are question.

Comment: @cxw Oh, thank you (didn't mean to solicit "points" :).  I am all for being called (or -1-ed) when I mess up but I don't like the all-too-many downvotes that I see around that are completely unclear, even upon good consideration.

Comment: @zdim No worries - my upvote was entirely on the merits :) .  Happy hacking!

Comment: @zdim. I will test, but I think this should suffice. Upvoted.